# SQL IF ELSE statement in trigger

Tags: oracle, if-statement, triggers, compiler-errors, ora-00936

I want to trigger every insert on a table. Sometimes the name_event is the repository of the target table available and can this be inserted. Sometimes it's unavailable and than I need to check the code in the folder table:

```
create or replace TRIGGER scheme2.Logger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON scheme2.payments
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO scheme1.db(ID, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
    VALUES(  :NEW.id 
          ,  IF (select repo.code 
                   from scheme2.repository repo
                  where repo.id = :NEW.repository_id) IS NOT NULL
             THEN 
                (select repo.code
                   from scheme2.pay_repository repo
                  where repo.id = :NEW.repository_id)
             ELSE
                (select env.repository_code 
                   from scheme2.folder env
                  where env.id = :NEW.folder_id)
          , SYSDATE);
END;
```

This code I tried, but I got compile errors:

```
Error(2,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Line 2 is the line for each row

```
Error(4,5): PL/SQL: ORA-00936: Unknown expression.
```

Line 4 is the insert into line

How to fix the errors?

Comment: honestly its not clarify for me what you want , however why dont you set before the insert a variable for name event .....example .... select repo.code into VAR_EVENT  from scheme2.repository repo where repo.id = :NEW.repository_id ..... if VAR_EVENT  is null then ... select ... from..

Comment: when your done with the checking of the variable , insert it in the table

Comment: Moudiz, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
create or replace TRIGGER scheme2.Logger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON scheme2.payments
    FOR EACH ROW
   declare
   VAR_NEVENT  number(3);

    BEGIN

   select repo.code into VAR_NEVENT from scheme2.repository repo
   where repo.id = :NEW.repository_id)

     IF VAR_NEVENT  IS NOT NULL THEN 
    select repo.code INTO VAR_NEVENT from scheme2.pay_repository repo where repo.id =  :NEW.repository_id

 ELSE (select env.repository_code into VAR_NEVENT  from scheme2.folder env where env.id = :NEW.folder_id)
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO scheme1.db(ID, NAME_EVENT, TIME_EVENT)
    VALUES(:NEW.id, VAR_NEVENT  , SYSDATE);
    END;
```

Something similar to the above .. first select your result in a variable then insert it in a table.

Comment: don't you need to do make your select in the else also in the var?

Comment: yes ofcourse , I fixed it , anyway it was a quick example.

Comment: I got following Error starting at line : 3 in command -
VAR_NEVENT  VARCHAR(50)
Error report -
Unknown Command           04079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
*Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
*Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

Comment: @Guil maybe the declare was missing i fixed , however the answer is just an example. I didnt create the trigger from my side